# How to use nfs to mount my LAN disk into cloud server?

Tags: networking, mount, nfs

I have two machine.

one is in my `LAN`, which dont have public ip(cant access if not in my ethernet).

the other is a cloud server(aws), which can provide me a public ip address.

So, i can use `autossh` to map `LAN` ip out by cloud server, using this command:

```
autossh -M 8889 -NR *:8888:192.168.1.24:22 root@32.23.4.5 -o TCPKeepAlive=yes -o ServerAliveInterval=30
```

then i can access my LAN by:

```
ssh -p 8888 root@32.23.4.5
```

now, what i want is:

I have one data disk(very big) in my `LAN` server, which i want my cloud server can access this disk.

but the normal nfs command is:

```
mount -rw -t nfs 32.23.4.5:/QData /QData
```

i cant specify port, could you help on this?

How can i use `nfs` to mount my `LAN` server's disk?

Comment: You have not advised the OS's or really the use case. I suspect this is an XY question - NFS is a horrible tool for file sharing, and, while likely doable, using SSH to allow nfs access has got to be a lot more painful then less hacky solutions like using a VPN or sshfs.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/377170/which-ports-do-i-need-to-open-in-the-firewall-to-use-nfs discusses the ports and some of the challenges with NFS.  Its really not a nice protocol. Certainly there is a lot more to it then mapping across port 8888 which your solution seems to centre around.

Comment: Are you wanting to access your files from anywhere, using the AWS EC2 instance to get round your IP limitations? If so, how publicly available should the data be?

Comment: thanks @davidgo for reply. my OS is centos 8, my question in one word is: how my ec2 can read the files in my LAN server. for my data publicity, it's ok to open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this.

Be aware that having NFS open to the public is a major security risk to your home network, and can land up costing money in AWS data transfer fees.   (No way I would do this).

If I had to use NFS as per the question, I would set up a VPN server (eg OpenVPN) on the EC2 instance.  I would then set up a VPN client from the NFS server.  In that way you are creating a tunnel through your Dynamic IP and NAT connection so the VPN server can then see the NFS server on an RFC1918 address.  (RFC1918 addresses are commonly known as private addresses, eg 192.168.x.x and 10.x.x.x)

You then have options on the EC2 instance.

**I would not do this because of the security implications** - You could set up port forwarding on IPTABLES so that anything that hits the EC2 instance on a port other then 22 is redirected through to the NFS server.  There are tutorials on how to do this - eg https://www.debuntu.org/how-to-redirecting-network-traffic-to-a-new-ip-using-iptables/  and https://wiki.vpsget.com/index.php/Forward_(redirect/nat)_traffic_with_iptables

A better way would be to set up a second VPN from your remote device to the EC2 instance, in that way you can connect to your NFS server across the VPN, relaying the data through the EC2 instance.  This also means the NFS server is not exposed to the world.

An alternative would be to just ditch AWS and find a VPN provider that offers you a static IP address, and connect to that from your NFS server (again, I would not do this because it exposes your NFS server to the world, but its a lot easier then running your own VPN server, and if you factor bandwidth costs into account cheaper as well)

While using a VPN is a robust way of doing things (and I would deploy it in a solution I rolled out), there are easier ways.

SSH is a great protocol - it is designed with security in mind, and its simple (only talks on 1 port).  It also supports all manner of file transfers.  You can set up a reverse tunnel using just SSH and then rely on SSH to do everything you need.  This is likely the kind of thing you were attempting in your question, but you were missing a few bits.   I'm not an expert with this, but the solution would likely be something like:

After starting ssh on your NFS server - On the NFS server a command like

```
 ssh -R 11022:127.0.0.1:22 user@ec2.ip.add.ress
```

The above command will create a reverse tunnel from your NFS server to the EC2 instance - When people connect to port 11022 on localhost on your EC instance it will connect to port 22 on your NFS server

To allow remote users connecting on your  EC2 server and be relayed to your NFS server's SSH connection you need to open up your NFS server.  This could be done as follows (on the EC2 instance):

```
 # Allow forwarding to localhost in Kernel
 sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1

 # Firewall rule to allow forwarding
 iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp -d ec2.ip.add.ress -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:11022
 
 # Allow connections to port 11022
 iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 11022 -j ACCEPT
```

Note that you will additionally need to configure the networking for your EC2 instance to accept connections on port 11022 - I believe this is done somewhere in AWS, but outside your EC2 instance.

At this point people with the login credentials for your NFS server will be able to SSH into it.   Once they can do this you can share files with them.  There are a lot of options here.

The easiest would be to use scp or sftp - both programs are means to use SSH to copy files.  SFTP presents similarly to an FTP server, but uses the SFTP program.

There are also programs which will allow you to create a virtual filesystem over SSH.  On Linux there is a program called sshfs which will allow you to mount the NFS filesystem across ssh to provide a similar virtual file to NFS.

I comment that I have not used this for long term file sharing - and that it will only be as reliable as your SSH connection.

Comment: thanks david. it helps